# for loop to make hopscotch structure?

Tags: java, for-loop, nested, nested-loops

I'm supposed to return this:

```
   1
2     3
   4
5     6
   7
8     9
   10
```

if I call the method as hopscotch(3);

I'm getting excessive output with this code:

```
public static void hopscotch(int hops){
    String space = " ";
    int numbers = 1;
      for (int i = 1; i <= hops; hops++){
          System.out.print(space);
          System.out.println(numbers);

          numbers++;
          System.out.print(numbers);
          numbers++;
          System.out.print(space);
          System.out.print(numbers);
          numbers++;
      }
}
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.
Do I need a nested for loop?

Comment: This may help you with the design too: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/344371-hopscotch-program/. or you can just do a Google search for "java print hopscotch board" and look at the top result ;)

Answer (score 1):

The reason you were getting excessive output is because you were increasing the
`hops` variable in your `for` loop. Notice your `hops++` in the loop constructor. You should instead be increasing you loop counter, which you have designated as `i`. So, you can fix this (and remove the extra lines you are getting) by replacing `hops++` with `i++`.

I ran a test using a main method, doing the following (I just hard coded 5 hops):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int hops = 5;
    int currentNum = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i <= hops; i++) {

        System.out.print("    ");
        System.out.println(currentNum);
        currentNum++;

        System.out.print(" " + currentNum);
        currentNum++;
        System.out.println("    " + currentNum);
        currentNum++;

    }
    System.out.print("    ");
    System.out.println(currentNum);

}
```

And got the output:

```
    1
 2    3
    4
 5    6
    7
 8    9
    10
 11    12
    13
 14    15
    16
```

Answer (score 0):

To address "I'm getting excessive output with this code", change this:

```
 for (int i = 1; i <= hops; hops++){
```

To this:

```
 for (int i = 1; i <= hops; i++){
```